# is it possible to use different sessions in em-http-request multi?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, eventmachine

I need to make em-http-request multi request to server with some sessions. Is it possible?

I get urls in response with sessionId parameter, it is the same for all requests. But it should be different, i.e.:

```
example.com?sessionId=AabBcC
example.com?sessionId=DdEeFf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Don't know what else to say given that level of abstraction.

Comment: yes :),  my problem was with object references, array what I use to store results, actually, was array of references to one object.